# converting ocaml function to stream

Tags: stream, ocaml

Say I have the following block of OCaml code:

```
let genblocks () =
  let blocks = ref [] in
  let rec loop depth block =
    let iter i = loop (depth - 1) (i :: block) in
    match depth with
      | 0 -> blocks := block :: !blocks
      | _ -> List.iter iter [1;2;3;4]
  in
  loop 4 [];
  !blocks
```

This generates a list of lists: `[[1;1;1;1]; [1;1;1;2]; ...; [4;4;4;4]]`.

Now, I want to convert this to a stream (using the `Stream` module or something similar).  However, I'm at a loss as to how to do this while still maintaining the overall recursive structure of the current code. The reason I would like to maintain this structure is that it enables me to easily prune out lists containing certain properties during generation.  For example, with this code structure, during generation I can easily prune out, say, lists containing the sublist `[1;1]`.  (The above is just a toy example and my actual application is more complicated...).

Any hints/ideas/pointers on how to convert the above piece of code into a "streaming" instance?  I'm sort of stuck with the inability to "backtrack" once depth of zero is hit...

**edit:** Another way of looking at the problem: is there a way to transform `genblocks` to get rid of the list reference?  This seems like the first step needed to make it stream-compatible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three different things in my answer:

1. a demonstration of a generic technique to get rid of your mutable variable
2. an algorithim-specific technique that makes it very easy to produce a stream
3. a link to a generic technique to turn any producer into an on-demand stream

First, let's make your algorithm generic in the basis of the enumeration:

```
let genblocks n =
  (* base = [1; ... ; n] *)
  let base = Array.to_list (Array.init n (fun i -> i+1)) in
  let blocks = ref [] in
  let rec loop depth block =
    let iter i = loop (depth - 1) (i :: block) in
    match depth with
      | 0 -> blocks := block :: !blocks
      | _ -> List.iter iter base
  in
  loop n [];
  !blocks
```

Without looking at what the code does for now, there is a very easy
way to get rid of the enumeration: turn any function of type `A -> B`
that uses a mutable type with type `C` into a function of type `A *
C -> B * C` that receives the state, and returns its modified value --
this is what is called the "state monad". So I will simply add an
additional parameter `blocks` to your functions `loop` and `iter`, and
make it return not `unit` but `int list list`:

```
let genblocks n =
  let base = Array.to_list (Array.init n (fun i -> i+1)) in
  let rec loop depth blocks block =
    let iter blocks i = loop (depth - 1) blocks (i :: block) in
    match depth with
      | 0 -> block :: blocks
      | _ -> List.fold_left iter blocks base
  in
  loop n [] []
```

Now let's look at what this algorithm exactly does:

```
# genblocks 3;;
- : int list list =
[[3; 3; 3]; [2; 3; 3]; [1; 3; 3]; [3; 2; 3]; [2; 2; 3]; [1; 2; 3]; [3; 1; 3];
 [2; 1; 3]; [1; 1; 3]; [3; 3; 2]; [2; 3; 2]; [1; 3; 2]; [3; 2; 2]; [2; 2; 2];
 [1; 2; 2]; [3; 1; 2]; [2; 1; 2]; [1; 1; 2]; [3; 3; 1]; [2; 3; 1]; [1; 3; 1];
 [3; 2; 1]; [2; 2; 1]; [1; 2; 1]; [3; 1; 1]; [2; 1; 1]; [1; 1; 1]]
```

When called with argument 3 (in your code 4 is hardcoded), this
algorithms returns all the 3-combinations of the numbers 1, 2 and
3. Said otherwise, it enumerates all the three-digits numbers in
a numeration system in base 3 (using digits between 1 and 3 instead of
0 and 2 as usual).

There is a very simple way to enumerate numbers that you learned in
school: to go from a number to the next, simply increment
(or decrement) it. In your case, the list starts with the "big" number
and goes to the "small" one, so we're going to decrement. With the
fact that your base is [1; N] rather than [0; N-1], the decrementation
function is written

```
let decr n block =
  let rec decr n = function
    | [] -> raise Exit
    | 1::rest -> n :: decr n rest
    | i::rest -> (i - 1) :: rest
  in try Some (decr n block) with Exit -> None
```

I made it return None when we reach 0 (in your system, [1;1;1..]) to
easily stop the enumeration at this point.

```
decr 3 [3;3;3];;
- : int list option = Some [2; 3; 3]
# decr 3 [1;2;3];;
- : int list option = Some [3; 1; 3]
# decr 3 [1;1;1];;
- : int list option = None
```

From this function it is trivial to enumerate all digits:

```
let start n = Array.to_list (Array.make n n)

let genblocks n =
  let rec gen = function
    | None -> []
    | Some curr -> curr :: gen (decr n curr)
  in gen (Some (start n))
```

But the important point is that the whole state of the generation is
stored in one value only, the current number. So you can easily turn
it into a Stream:

```
let genblocks n =
  let curr = ref (Some (start n)) in
  Stream.from (fun _ ->
    match !curr with
      | None -> None
      | Some block ->
        curr := (decr n block);
        Some block
  )

# Stream.npeek 100 (genblocks 3);;
- : int list list =
[[3; 3; 3]; [2; 3; 3]; [1; 3; 3]; [3; 2; 3]; [2; 2; 3]; [1; 2; 3]; [3; 1; 3];
 [2; 1; 3]; [1; 1; 3]; [3; 3; 2]; [2; 3; 2]; [1; 3; 2]; [3; 2; 2]; [2; 2; 2];
 [1; 2; 2]; [3; 1; 2]; [2; 1; 2]; [1; 1; 2]; [3; 3; 1]; [2; 3; 1]; [1; 3; 1];
 [3; 2; 1]; [2; 2; 1]; [1; 2; 1]; [3; 1; 1]; [2; 1; 1]; [1; 1; 1]]
```

Is there a generic way to transform producer-driven functions
(that accumulate items at the rythm most natural according to
the problem) into consumer-driven function (that produce elements one
at the time, when decided by the consumer)? Yes, and I explain it in
the following blog post:

[Generators, iterators, control and continuations](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/generators-iterators-control-and-continuations/)

The big idea is that you can, by mechanic but complex transformations
of your code, make explicit what the "context" of the producer is,
what his current state, as encoded as a complex mess of values and
control flow (which calls have been made, in which conditional branch
are you at this point). This context is then turned into a value, that
you can use, as the "numbers" used here, to derive a consumer-driven
stream.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this code isn't homework then you can pretty much translate your code to return a "stream" verbatim by using the `Enum` module in [batteries](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatEnum.html). Namely the functions `Enum.push` and `Enum.empty`. The stream module that comes with OCaml is extremely minimal as you've probably noticed. It's better to use an alternative.

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong, `Enum.push` would allow me to _construct_ the stream, but I would have still have to construct the entire stream first before I could empty it (that is, I believe using `Enum.push` would have the same effect as using `Stream.of_list !blocks` in the last line of the code).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours, so I developed an iterator module (it's definitely not new but I was not able able to find a simple package that did the same thing)

Here is a link : https://github.com/JoanThibault/DAGaml/blob/master/tools/iter.mli

With this module you can re-write your code in

```
open IterExtra (* add some handy symbols to manipulate iterators *)
let genblock n = (Iter.range 1 (4+1)) $^ n
val genblock : int -> int list Iter.iter
```

now if you want to filter it with some function `prune : int list -> bool` :

```
let genblock n = (Iter.range 1 (4+1)) $^ n |> Iter.filter prune
val genblock : int -> int list Iter.iter
```

Finally, you can iterate over your iterator with some printing function `print : int list -> unit` :

```
let n = 10;;
Iter.iter print (genblock n);;
```